# Возможно ли в логах nginx посмотреть входящие POST-запросы?

Tags: nginx

Возникла такая проблема - мне пришли не все отправленные через форму данные.
Сохраняет ли nginx POST-запросы?
Если да, то где? В */var/log/nginx/* комманда *grep* не нашла отправленные мною данные. Где еще можно поискать и имеет ли смысл?

Comment: FireBug спасает часто

Comment: Я уже проверил в нем - данные на сервер уходят. Проблема в backend-e.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно, если настроить собственный [формат лога](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLogModule), например:

```
location = /api/ {
  log_format logpost $request_body;
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/post.log  logpost;
}
```

Переменная [`$request_body`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24request_body) содержит тело запроса — post-данные.

Comment: крутотень, спасибо

Comment: А если сейчас у меня в конфиге nginx это нигде не упоминается, то выходит нет даже смысла искать то что мне нужно?

Comment: Значит, сейчас используется дефолтный формат лога — см. про ["combined"](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLogModule#log_format). Есть смысл создать свой и использовать его — напр. дописать `$request_body` в конце дефолтного. Но имейте в виду, что будет большой объем данных. Есть смысл прописать такой подробный логгинг только для определенных URL.

Comment: Но это будет действовать только для новых запросов?

Comment: Только для новых.

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь буду думать, что делать - исправлять форму или все все что пришло - смотреть через логи nginx :)